# How do I route to an application serving static content on an absolute path

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I work for a large organization that needs to go through approval process for DNS records, recently I requested a wildcard DNS and was rejected stating they do not give wildcard DNS records. Cloud is still very new to all of us as an organization.

If I have a bunch of applications that we are deploying with frontends that serve their content in an absolute path `<link href=/css/app.c4234350.css rel=stylesheet>`. Is there a way to serve all of these applications on a single DNS record using path prefixes? or would all of these applications need to have their own DNS record?

We are using nginx-controller as our ingress controller. The specific applications I am thinking about are ArgoCD UI and Dependency Track UI.

I have tried a few things using rewrite rules in the ingress and sending the assets to the root path, however that does not work as the controller does not understand which ingress to route the request to since it is coming in as

`route.com/asset.css`

instead of the defined rule of

`route.com/argocd/asset`

or

`route.com/dependency-track/asset.css`

and both of these applications cannot have a rule of

`route.com`

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to handle it

### Way #1 rewrite (easier but might not work for all apps)

This approach is about `rewrite` feature of Nginx Controller ([doc here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target))

Based on example from doc you will have something like this

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /argo-cd(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: argo-cd-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Down side of this approch is when frontend(or any other app) return links it will not know that it's in sub path and links will be broken

### Way #2 Application in sub-path (better but need application changes if not supported)

This approach is to tell your app that it is not working at `/` but on sub-path in case in Agro CD there is a support for it and you can read about it [here](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#argocd-server-and-ui-root-path-v153). You just need to provide argument `--rootpath` with what you like for example `/argo-cd` then you can create ingress rule like this

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: agro-cd
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /argo-cd
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: argo-cd-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

This might need code changes if it's not supported, but when it works there is no issues if application generated any links

### Way #3 DNS

As you already mention in the question it's just to create one sub domain for each application, probably the best as there is not need to code changes also there are not issues with links generated by the applications