# k8s - nginx ingress: force sending a client a redirect

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress setup that works correctly:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.provider: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: kube-blahblah
  namespace: kubernetes-blahblah
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /blahblah/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: some-service
            port:
              number: 443
```

if you use a path like `http://somehost:someport/blahblah/`. The application that is mapped shows up without issues and the resources that are *inside* `/blahblah/` also show up without issues... say...  a file that is linked with `"src=somefile.html"` will be requested as  `http://http://somehost:someport/blahblah/somefile.html` and it shows up fine.

However, if I request `http://somehost:someport/blahblah` (no trailing `/`), it shows a 404 as it is not mapped. I tried adding a separate ingress like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.provider: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: kube-just-blahblah
  namespace: kubernetes-blahblah
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /blahblah
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: some-service
                port:
                  number: 443
```

This works in terms of *connecting* the path to the resource that would come from requesting `http://somehost:someport/blahblah/` *however* resources that are linked inside `blahblah/` break from the client's POV. For example a file called `file1.html`, which should be requested with `http://somehost:someport/blahblah/file1.html` *and works*, the client will request it as `http://somehost:someport/file1` (because the original request was made without a trailing `/` after `/blahblah`).

A different ingress with a *configuration-snippet* can take care of the mapping of `blahblah`:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/blahblah)$ .$1/ permanent;
```

But `configuration-snippet` is discouraged because of security issues .... so I wonder if there is a *simple* way to setup an ingress so that when the request is made for `/blahblah` the ***client*** can get a redirect to `/blahblah/` (with the trailing `/`) without connecting to the service... then the client will make a request for `http://somehost:someport/blahblah/` abd problem is solved. Something like a different `backend`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/blahblah(/|$)(.*)` instead of `/blahblah/(.*)` from the first snippet.

Also with this change you need to change `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` (only 1 to 2), so there will be no issues with accessing path `/blahblah`

[More info about rewrite here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

Comment: I have a hunch that won't work because if you request `/blahblah` _and it worked_ (even without the second ingress, which is what this answer apparently solves), you will still end up with a document that provides links that will be broken as they won't be requested within `/blahblah/`.... that's the reason I think the _client_ should be notified about requesting `/blahblah/` with a redirect. I will check it, just in case.

Comment: Yeap.... with this adjustment to the ingress to serve `/blahblah`, even though it does serve the content of `/blahblah/` with just one ingress, the underlying problem is still there... because the client is _not_ aware that it's coming from `/blahblah/`, the resoirces that should be requested as `/blahblah/x` will be requested as `/x` which won't fly.

Comment: You can read what I wrote [here way #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77841806/21863762) I don't know what application it is, if it support `rootPath` or `webContext`(two names for the same thing) probably will resolve your issue. Or maybe we should start why the app is not server at `/`?

Comment: About the question about why the app is not served from `/` is not relevant.... you would encounter this same problem with this app if you had multiple `paths` defined in the ingress, right?

Comment: I think yes, because the root cause is not the ingress but app that doesn't know that it's working in some context so it generating wrong links. Normally app should only one ingress route. Because of this you will end up creating route for almost all possible path generated by the app and if in some case will start collide with app that is working at `/` there is no solution (at least I don't know). Other example I had to deploy sonarqube to k8s and there is env `SONAR_WEB_CONTEXT` setting this, one route and everything work with no issues