# Kubernetes nginx ingress returning 400

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, docker-desktop

What I did:

1. Install Docker Desktop for Windows
2. Enabled Kubernetes (throught "Settings" -> "Kubernetes" -> "Enable Kubernetes")
3. Installed Nginx Ingress via YAML manifest: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/
4. Installed kubernetes-dashboard via YAML manifest: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui
5. Checked that dashboard services and pods working fine:
   [image]
6. Took a minimal Ingress example (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) and created ingress manifest on it:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: root-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

7. Ingress was succefuly started.
   [image]
8. I am keep getting 400 response from that path.
   [image]
9. curl -k -v https://localhost response on localhost:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> curl.exe -k -v https://localhost
    *   Trying [::1]:443...
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 443
    * schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
    * ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
    * ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
    * using HTTP/1.1
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost
    > User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
    > Accept: */*
    >
    * schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
    * schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
    * schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
    * schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
    < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    < Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 20:20:40 GMT
    < Content-Type: text/html
    < Content-Length: 146
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
    <
    <html>
    <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx</center>
    </body>
    </html>
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

10. curl -k -v https://localhost response on localhost/dashboard:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> curl.exe -k -v https://localhost/dashboard
    *   Trying [::1]:443...
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 443
    * schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
    * ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
    * ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
    * using HTTP/1.1
    > GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost
    > User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
    > Accept: */*
    >
    * schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
    * schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
    * schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
    * schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
    < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    < Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 20:23:04 GMT
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
    <
    Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Can you add output from `curl -k -v https://localhost` using command line?

Comment: @zori I added p.9 and p.10 in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick fix

Just use NodePort

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-service
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8443
      targetPort: 8443
      nodePort: 31000
```

Dashboard will be available at https://localhost:31000

### Root cause

What you are sending looks like this
Browser ==HTTPS==> ingress ==HTTP==> k8s-dashboard
But expected is
Browser ==HTTPS==> ingress ==HTTPS==> k8s-dashboard

The issues it that `k8s-dashboard` service expects **HTTPS** request, this is the reason why you get `Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.`
It was decrypted by ingress and later on forward by using plain **HTTP**

### Solution

#### 1 Export TCP port without using ingress

Instead of using ingress you can use NodePort (I gave it in Quick fix) or LoadBalancer. Idea is to work on ISO Layer 4(IP) instead of routing it using Layer 7(HTTP)

#### 2 Use `ssl-passthrough` from nginx-ingress

To make it work it needs two changes

1. Modify nginx ingress controller using `kubectl edit`

```bash
kubectl -n ingress-nginx edit deployment ingress-nginx-controller
```

You have to add `- --enable-ssl-passthrough`(just one line) to the `args`
After change it should look like

```yaml
...
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-nginx-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
        - --enable-ssl-passthrough
...
```

2. Add proper ingress route

When route is created you can't specify path like `/dashboard` because k8s dashboard doesn't know it's working in some subpath, so using `rewrite` will not resolve it as links generated by dashboard will be wrong(I wrote more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77841806/21863762))

So we need ingress route like this (with `ssl-passthrough` and `backend-protocol`)

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: root-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```

### 3 Disable https in kubernetes dashboard (I didn't try)

When you disable HTTPS in kubernetes dashboard your flow will look like this
Browser ==HTTPS==> ingress ==HTTP==> k8s-dashboard

It will perfectly match what you have right now and should work without issues
As I didn't try it I will leave [this article](https://vividcode.io/disable-authentication-and-https-in-kubernetes-dashboard/) how to do it.
There is also [raw manifest](https://vividcode.io/content/insecure-kubernetes-dashboard.yml) but maybe a little old

Comment: huge thanks again! You save me two days in the row :)

Comment: I did second solution and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

- Apply and connect to a nettool pod into your K8s.

Else expose the 443 on your local machine for using curl